# Queries on large number of small sets and lists

Tags: python, list, set, graph-theory

I need to do some calculations on triangular/tetrahedral meshes in 2 and 3 dimensions. Tasks like the following arise:

- Given a list of vertices V and a list of 3-tuples T indexing into V.
  For each vertex v in V, find the indices of all 3-tuples in T
  referring to v.
- Interpreting T as a triangulation where the 3-tuples are triangles, find all 2-tuples representing the edges between vertices of the triangulation.
- For each of those edges, find the index of all triangles indcident to it. (Also in 3D with 4-tuples and polyhedrons instead of triangles.)

I think it could be done with list comprehensions, but I extremely worry about performance when scaling to 100'000s or 1'000'000s of triangles. I also had a look into Scipy's graph library, but that's rather about finding paths in graph and stuff.

I wonder whether Python offers some good functions to do it, or how the problem is named in order to start a good search.

Comment: What are the constraints of `V`? Maybe post a rough implementation that we can then optimize?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: There's no implementation yet. But maybe that's actually a good idea.

Comment: Are the elements of V just the vertices in T?  Do you mean that a typical element of T will be (v1, v2, v3) where v1, v2, and v3 are elements of V?  Or can some triangles have vertices that aren't in V?  This may be a "simplicial decomposition" which is a special kind of triangulation (in any number of dimensions.)  Then again, it may not be; you haven't told us much about the problem.  I'm not sure that it will help if it is simplicial, but google "simplex" and "simplicial complex" to find out if that's what you've got.